# How to import local package in GO

Tags: go

I am creating a web API.

I built my server and controller in the same file `main.go`.

I created another file name `model.go` where I declare a `Person` struct.

I can't export my model in `main.go`.

Every time I run or build I get this error :

```
can't load package: package .: found packages main
```

Is there a way to export func/const and import them in file with good path? (Like the way JavaScript works).

**This is my tree:**

```
myapp/
  --main.go/
  --model.go/
```

**This is my import:** 
**main.go**

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "log"
   "net/http"

   "./person"
   "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)
```

**model.go**

```
package person

type Person struct {
   ID        string   `json:"id,omitempty"`
   Firstname string   `json:"firstname,omitempty"`
   Lastname  string   `json:"lastname,omitempty"`
   Address   *Address `json:"address,omitempty"`
}

var people []Person
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

within the same folder you must have the same package name.

When golang processes imports it loads all files under the same directory as a whole.

given the code you presented, model.go package name must be main.

You simply don t need to import model.go from main.go.

Now, there s a little thing to know about. When you will run go build/run/install, it will take the list of files passed as parameters to initialize the build process.

In your current setup that means you must pass all files composing the main package to the command line, otherwise, they will be ignored, in your case that means a build failure.

In plain text, you will do `go build *.go` instead of `go build main.go`

In the future if you want to avoid multiple source files to build, you should have a unique main.go, with the minimum code in it to initialize the program you are writing. As a consequence the content of `model.go` will exist within a different package (directory), and will be imported into main via an `import xyz` statement.

Finally, import path of the `import` directives must not be relative to the current working directory. They are all `GOPATH/src` based.

Comment: Worth noting that import paths _can_ be relative, but relative import paths, though possible, should _never ever EVER_ be used.  _EVER!_

Comment: ~~in main package, might be ok, although bad practice. Also, testing will use a different package name within same folder.

Comment: Tests _can_ use a different package name in the same folder, but only with a very specific pattern (`packagename_test`), and only then if blackbox testing is more useful than whitebox testing (which functionally precludes proper unit tests in most cases).

Comment: Files that end in `_test` are not included during a `go build`, `go install`, or `go run` command.  You can verify this with, for example, the following setup: https://pastebin.com/xVnsdghE.  The global variable defined in the test file is not accessible from the non-test file, and is not included in the final build, despite them being in the same package.